# How is a positive horror rating handled?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

What does a positive horror rating mean? For example, when a monster has -1 horror rating and my character's willpower is 7, it is reduced to 6. In the positive rating, when the monster has 1 for horror rating, should I add 1 to my willpower?

Answer (score 8):

**Yes**,

Horror tests are an attribute test, which are defined on page 13 of the rules, emphasis mine.

> Occasionally, an investigator must make a modified attribute
>   test. Such tests always list a **positive or negative number** after the attribute (for example: “Test Strength –1”). This number is always added to the investigator’s attribute before rolling the die. In this way, a skill test with a negative modifier is more likely to fail.

Comment: Which makes sense. I mean, a woman in rags is creepy, sure, but it shouldn't drive a hardened gangster INSANE.